# Way to go direct to defined screen in ReactNative and OneSignal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, onesignal

I have integrated with OneSignal in my app for push notification, right now I need to handle when user click on the notification.

When user click on the notification, App have to go to screen that have defined in OneSignal but instead of immediately go to defined screen, it land on main screen until receiving event from OneSignal (onOpened event) complete.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
    }

  onOpened(openResult) {
    const data = openResult.notification.payload.additionalData;
    if(data.screen) {
      navigationService.navigate(data.screen);
    }
  }
```

Do we have any way to let it go direct to defined screen? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't this work? Is the value of the data.screen normal?

Comment: Yes, I can navigate to data.screen value, but the behavior right now is:
```user click notification -> go to main screen ( wait till the onOpened complete)-> go to defined screen.```
Can we do like this 
```user click notification -> go to defined screen.```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentWillmount`

```js
componentWillmount(openResult) {
   this.onOpened(openResult);
}
```

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: The componentWillmount starts before the screen is rendered. Doesn't this work?

Comment: When you create a component, the component -> componentWillMount -> render -> componentDidMount is followed.

Comment: it still pending some second in main screen before go to defined screen. Is that correct behaviour?